# Stationarity Test on Dataset

Tags: noise, statistics

I have a nice and clean noise signal sampled at a fixed rate for several hours. When I calculate the PSD I see it's pure flicker noise. But I don't know much about the process.

I've seen some discussion in articles about wether flicker noise is stationary or not, it doesn't look like a settled issue.

How can I check for stationarity in a simple way on my dataset? (If that is possible!)

I was reading about methods to check for stationarity like Dickey-Fuller – GLS (ERS), but that looks like it's beyond my knowledge in statistics (what's a unit root?), I wondered if there is a shortcut or at least a tutorial I could follow.

Comment: Interesting question! It looks like [unit root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_root) means that the AR model fitted to the data has a pole on the unit circle. In DSP terms, that means the AR model is (critically) unstable.  [This github repository](https://github.com/ECheynet/stationaryTests) seems to have some matlab code that does something similar. And there is a Python tutorial [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-data-stationary-python/).

Comment: Hi: there are two different types of ts stationarity weak and strong. the df  test for a unit root test is  a very specific type of non-stationarity. but, if you want to test for weak stationarity ( in a more general way ), you should check for whether the mean and the variance of the series are constant over the life of the series. There are a few different ways to do this. one is to just do it visually by plotting the series. Another way is to use a structural break test ( tests for changes in mean ).  There are other ways. I would google for "testing for the weak stationarity of a series".